# I ned to get all the attached resources to VM using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Could you please help me out in powershell script for getting the attached resources to VM like Load balancers,storage,Public Ip,Disks,StorageAccount etc...

Comment: Hi Nagendra kumar; your question is really too broad for this site, which is about focussed specific questions.
However, if you have tried some powershell commands already and found specific problems when using them, that would be suitable for a question here.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using ***[`PowerShell Az Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-7.0.0)*** you can get the Resources attached to a Azure VM .

***You can use something like below :***

```
Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green "Please enter the VM name you would like to get Details:"
$VMName = Read-Host
$vm = Get-AzVm -Name $VMName
if ($vm) {
$RGName=$vm.ResourceGroupName
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'Resource Group Name is identified as-' $RGName
$diagSa = [regex]::match($vm.DiagnosticsProfile.bootDiagnostics.storageUri, '^http[s]?://(.+?)\.').groups[1].value
$osDiskName = $vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.Name
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'OS Disk Name is identified as-' $OsDiskName
$datadisks = $vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks
$ResourceID = (Get-Azdisk -Name $osDiskName).id
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'OS Disk Resource ID is identified as-' $ResourceID
if ($vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Count -gt 0) {
    foreach ($datadisks in $vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks){
    $datadiskname=$datadisks.name
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'Data Disk is identified as-' $datadiskname
    $ResourceID = (Get-Azdisk -Name $datadiskname).id
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'Data Disk Disk Resource ID is identified as-' $ResourceID
    }
}
$azResourceParams = @{
 'ResourceName' = $VMName
 'ResourceType' = 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
 'ResourceGroupName' = $RGName
}
$vmResource = Get-AzResource @azResourceParams
$vmId = $vmResource.Properties.VmId
$diagContainerName = ('bootdiagnostics-{0}-{1}' -f $vm.Name.ToLower().Substring(0, $i), $vmId)
$diagSaRg = (Get-AzStorageAccount | where { $_.StorageAccountName -eq $diagSa }).ResourceGroupName
$saParams = @{
  'ResourceGroupName' = $diagSaRg
  'Name' = $diagSa
}
if ($diagSa){
Get-AzStorageAccount @saParams | Get-AzStorageContainer | where {$_.Name-eq $diagContainerName} | Remove-AzStorageContainer -Force
}
else {
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "No Boot Diagnostics Disk found attached to the VM!"
}
foreach($nicUri in $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Id) {
   $nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $nicUri.Split('/')[-1]
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'NIC Resource ID is identified as-' $nicUri
   foreach($ipConfig in $nic.IpConfigurations) {
     if($ipConfig.PublicIpAddress -ne $null){
     Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'Public IP is identified as-' $ipconfig.PublicIpAddressText
     Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'Private IP is identified as-' $ipconfig.PrivateIpAddress
     ## if you have app gateway or load balancer then it can be queried here as  $ipConfig.GatewayLoadBalancerText ,$ipconfig.ApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPoolsText ,$ipconfig.LoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolsText
     }
    }
}
}
else{
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "The VM name entered doesn't exist in your connected Azure Tenant! Kindly check the name entered and restart the script with correct VM name..."
}
```

**Ouptut:**

[image]